# Replace hat strap with something softer

Tags: clothing

The rope that came with this hat is irritating to wear with the hat.

[image: Hat with strap]

I would like something softer.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to decide is whether you want softer cord or something flat? It seems to thread through holes quite easily so it's just a matter of finding soft cord, not too thick, if you just want a cord.

If you want something flat and soft, threading a neoprene glasses strap onto the existing cord (or two short lengths or cord with stop knots) should work well.

Comment: I found this. https://www.amazon.com/Neoprene-Glasses-Retainer-Eyeglass-Sunglass/dp/B00KHJYJ2Y/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=neoprene%2Bglasses%2Bstrap&qid=1563815783&s=gateway&sr=8-1&th=1 Not quite what I am looking for. Would prefer something with the same diameter throughtout.